# Altering a json value into an array

Tags: python

I'm trying to change a value in a nested json and turn it into an array.

This is the current json output:

```
print(response['Version']['Document'])

{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "ID": "000"
            "Resource": [
                "a----",
                "b----"
            ]
        }
        {
            "Resource": "c----"
        }
        {
            "ID": "000"
            "Resource": [
                "d----",
                "e----"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to turn the value `"Resource": "c----"` into an array, so the desired output would look like this:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "ID": "000"
            "Resource": [
                "a----",
                "b----"
            ]
        }
        {
            "Resource": [
                "c----"
            ]
        }
        {
            "Resource": [
                "d----",
                "e----"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What would be a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You can find data type of variable by using type() and check if variable is of type list then its okay and if not then you can convert it to list.

You can use following piece of code

```
    jsonData=response['Version']['Document']
    for elem in jsonData['Statement']:
        if(type(elem['Resource'])==list):
            pass
        else:
            elem['Resource']=[elem['Resource']]
```

Comment: Yes, this works. I have another similar problem, where the 'Statement' itself is a list. Can you look at the edit? Otherwise I'm accepting the answer and posting another question.

Comment: Please take a look at my new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65425495/altering-a-nested-json-list-of-values-into-an-array

Comment: you can apply similar approach to your another problem. I will make a comment on your other question.

Comment: I'm trying to apply it but having a bit of trouble. Please do make a comment :) I already accepted your answer

Comment: please check my answer on your other question. may be it will help you