# Altering a nested json list of values into an array

Tags: python

I'm trying to change a list of values in a nested json and turn it into an array.

This is the current json output for two examples:

```
Example 1:
print(response['Version']['Document'])

{
    "Version": "0001",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "----",
        "Action": "----",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
}

Example 2:
print(response['Version']['Document'])
{
    "Version": "0002",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "----",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to change the `Statement`, that is a list of values (for example 1) into an array but the values inside (Effect, Action and Resource) stay as list values.

I'm trying to make an if statement that will respect the second example (Example 2) already being an array.

Desired output:

```
Example 1:
print(response['Version']['Document'])

{
    "Version": "0001",
    "Statement": [
        {
        "Effect": "----",
        "Action": "----",
        "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

Example 2:
print(response['Version']['Document'])
{
    "Version": "0002",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "----",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

What would be a good solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check for its datatype

```
    if (type(response['Version']['Document']['Statement'])==list):
        pass
    else:
        response['Version']['Document']['Statement']=[response['Version']['Document']['Statement']]
```

Comment: Yes, this does exactly what I want it to. Thank you very much for both answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to replace the item:

```py
s = response['Version']['Document'][‘Statement’]
if not isinstance(s, list):
    response['Version']['Document'][‘Statement’] = [s]
```